Black Screen Modal Appears in Table Actions on Laravel Filament v3 Resource
I am using Laravel Filament v3 and encountered an issue when generating a resource. I generated the resource using the following command:
php artisan make:filament-resource Anggota --generate
The resource generation completed successfully, but I am experiencing strange behavior in the table view of the generated resource. Specifically:

When I perform a search, apply a filter, change the number of items displayed, or navigate to another page in the table, a black screen modal immediately appears.
To view the updated data (e.g., navigating to page 2), I have to manually reload the page. After reloading, the table correctly shows the intended data (e.g., page 2).

I didn’t modify anything from the default generated resource
Environment Details:

Laravel version: 10

Filament version: v3

PHP version: 8.2

Browser: Chrome
Before take action |
After take action


Here is what I have tried so far:

Ensuring that JavaScript and CSS assets are up to date.
Clearing cache using php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear.
Rechecking the generated code, but I didn’t modify anything from the default generated resource.



Ensure that Filament's assets are up-to-date and republish them with php artisan filament:publish --assets then clear cache.
Confirm that Livewire is installed and functional composer show livewire/livewire, and add it if not installed composer require livewire/livewire.
Publish Livewire's configuration and assets with php artisan livewire:publish.
Verify that the @livewireScripts and @livewireStyles directives are included in your layout file.
Check your browser console for errors like Alpine is not defined. If found, include Alpine.js in your layout <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>


I found the same issue in others github, this works on me
https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/15091
